# What is the smallest scope that would allow me to see how often a GitHub user pushes to their repo?

Tags: github, oauth, scope, github-api

I am starting a project that is a GitHub daily streak counter, that counts the number of consecutive days a user pushes to a repo. This is my first time using Oauth, and my first time really digging into any documentation. I am going to allow a user to sign in on their GitHub, but I want to have the smallest amount of permissions that will still allow me to see if they pushed that day, so it is a little easier to trust my application.

I read the [Scopes of OAuth apps - GitHub Docs page](https://docs.github.com/en/apps/oauth-apps/building-oauth-apps/scopes-for-oauth-apps#available-scopes) and it looks like the no scope option will do, but it doesn't expressly say the push history, and I don't want to code a bunch only to find out that I need a different scope. Has anyone had any experience with this type of project and knows which scope would be better?